# Logic Apps: Using the "items" function with an IF statement

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm using a Logic App that contains a FOR EACH called "For_each_Item_in_Items". The FOR EACH is running on an array from an SQL query. I'm interested in a column called "Exists" which contains a string of either "ABC" or "DEF".

To get this value I'm using a "Set variable" action as follows:

```
@{items('For_each_Item_in_Items')?['Exists']}
```

This works.

Now I need to take this expression in the "Set variable" action and use it in an IF statement. However I need help with the syntax.

I've tried the following with no success:

```
@{if(equals(items('For_each_Item_in_Items')?['Exists'], 'ABC'), '1', '2')}
@{if(equals({items('For_each_Item_in_Items')?['Exists']}, 'ABC'), '1', '2')}
@{if(equals(string(items('For_each_Item_in_Items')?['Exists']), 'ABC'), '1', '2')}
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from our end we found it was working fine by removing "{ }". i.e..

```
@if(equals(items('For_each_Item_in_Items')?['Exists'], 'ABC'), '1', '2')
```

**REFERENCES:**
[Reference guide for functions in expressions - Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#if)

Comment: Yes I found the same! Thanks for investigating! :)